# Spring Tool Suite IDE Integration with Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-tool-suite

Is it possible to integration into STS IDE, so that I can start/stop Kafka from the Boot Dashboard without having to do so from terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

If you run in Docker containers you could use a Docker plugin for Eclipse to start/stop your containers.

Confluent has an 'all-in-one' docker-compose.yml which gives you a single node cluster ready to go: https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html